# strtotime on invalid date - Is this a PHP bug or am I doing something dumb

Tags: php

Using php 5.5 I came across this.

```
var_dump(strtotime('2015-09-31'))
```

results in a valid value of 1443657600, which is the return value of:

```
strtotime('2015-10-01')
```

Is this a php bug or am I doing / thinking something stupid?

Comment: 30 days have September, April, June and November!

Comment: @TomFenech Isn't that the OP's point, `2015-09-31` being an invalid date?

Comment: It isn't a bug so much as a feature.... the function expects a date ___format___, not necessarily a valid date; and it will ___try___ to convert that formatted string to a unix timestamp to the best of its ability.... this includes trying to work with all the ambiguities of what we humans refer to as dates

Comment: @jeroen I guess so. Not sure what a valid answer to this question would be though. Perhaps the OP could clarify exactly what answer they're looking for? Is the question basically whether the overflow of days into months is documented?

Comment: The overflow is documented for mktime() but I don't believe it is for strtotime()

Comment: Note that you also have a similar result with DateTime objects

Comment: If you do need to validate a date first, then use the [checkdate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function

Comment: The reason this came up was because I was doing a routine to check for overlapping dates in an array. [{start,end},{start,end},..].  I assumed, incorrectly that I would get false on an incorrect value. Thanks for advice on checkdate().